# JavaScript Uncaught Error in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

my error is: `Uncaught: TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I am trying to automatically fill a form without hitting submit (I can do that manually, as there is no class or ID on the submit button--then it will re-enter the next set of information after I hit it.) I am also unsure how to do the wait function properly. I have looked it up and tried a few various ways to no avail.

```
var qu = ["Do they offer whois privacy for domain registrations? free or at cost?"];
var an = ["Yes, so and so offers domain privacy options for domain registration."];
var q = document.getElementByName("question");
var a = document.getElementByName("answer");
var i = 0;
var delay = 2500;

do {
    q.value = qu[i];
    a.value = an[i];
    i++;
} while (i < qu.length)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in there:

```
document.getElementsByName("question");
document.getElementsByName("answer");
```

[see MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

For the wait function you can use:

```
setTimeout( function(){
//do something
}, 500);
```

This will set a timeout (waiting time) for 500ms 
[see mdn for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByName` is not a function, it is instead `getElementsByName()`, and it doesn't return one element, it will return you NodeList,  so you will have to take care of that.